# libcurl4-gnutls-dev : Depends: libldap2-dev but it is not going to be installed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl

I am trying to install curl in my ubuntu server as I was getting this error whenever I am compiling my C++ code -

```
fatal error: curl.h: No such file or directory
```

Below is the error:

```
username@phx7b02c-ee1b:~$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl4-gnutls-dev : Depends: libldap2-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I am not sure what wrong I am doing here?

My kernel version:

```
username@phx7b02c-ee1b:~$ uname -a
Linux phx7b02c-ee1b 2.6.35-22-server #33-Ubuntu SMP Sun Sep 19 20:48:58 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And also whenever I do like this - I always get the curl version

```
curl --version 

curl 7.21.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18 Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

**Update:-**

This is what I got -

```
/etc/apt/preferences
-bash: /etc/apt/preferences: No such file or directory

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
-bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ebay-packages.list: Permission denied


/etc/apt/preferences.d/*
-bash: /etc/apt/preferences.d/*: No such file or directory


/etc/apt/sources.list
-bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied
```

Comment: What is the output of `apt-get install curl`?

Comment: This is the output I am getting - `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
`

Comment: OK, so `curl` is installed. What gives you the `curl.h` error? What happens if you run `curl www.google.com`?

Comment: I have my C++ code, that I was compiling using `make -j4` and that's why I got this error.. My firewall is blocking external curl call.. But when I do, I always get like this - `curl --version
curl 7.21.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
`

Comment: OK, you might have mentioned that in the first place :). Also, please [edit] your question to add new info rather than posting comments.

Comment: @terdon: I updated my question as well.. Thanks for suggestion..

Comment: There's something wrong with your package sources. Please post the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` as well as `/etc/apt/preferences` and `/etc/apt/preferences.d/*`. Make sure you've run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: @Gilles:should I run `/etc/apt/sources.list` directly as it is? or with `sudo /etc/apt/sources.list` and same with other command as well?

Comment: No, these aren't executable files. They're configuration files in a text format, post their content.

Comment: Updated my question with the details.. Let me know if there is anything else you want me to do.. Thanks..